# Delete GameCenter Leaderboard - iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, game-center, leaderboard

My game currently has four leaderboards for differently difficulties, however this is going to change in a new update.

I no longer want to make use of all of these, but only one. How can I setup the new version to only use this new leaderboard and have the other hidden so they can't be seen by the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to iTunes Connect:

> Once a leaderboard has gone live for
>   any version of your app, it cannot be
>   removed.

Comment: can we Reset the leaderboard score?

Comment: Is test flight "beta" release considered live for this purpose? Or we can still remove leaderboard after some beta-testing?

Answer (score 1):

You may update your game without having any pointers to the current Game Center achievements system or leaderboards. This will mean that your players won't see any buttons that lead them to the Game Center overlay in your app, however the leaderboards and achievements will always be accessible through Game Center application under your game name and will not disassociate the score from the player.

UPDATE: 
You may delete scores manually.

'ITC->App Name->Manage Game Center->Manage Scores and Players->Manage->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove->Remove.....'