# How to clear live gamecenter leaderboard data?

Tags: ios, hide, reset, leaderboard

Is it possible to clear the data of a live gamecenter leaderboard (not sandbox one)?

If its not possible to clear, is there a way to hide a leaderboard from showing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reset a Game Center leaderboard category or to remove a category once it's been launched in a live app.

Once a leaderboard has gone live for any version of your app, it cannot be removed.

From posts:

- [Delete Leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477380/delete-gamecenter-leaderboard-itunes-connect)
- [Reset Leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288387/any-way-to-programmatically-reset-leaderboards)

Answer (score 6):

Go to that leaderboard in iTunesConnect and change the Score Range to something out of bounds. For example some of my golfers were posting scores that were way to far under par. I set my range to 1000 to 1001, and it deleted all of the scores which were already in the range of about -30 to +30. I later changed it back to the correct range. This however won't fix old versions of the game submitting scores that are out of range...

Comment: If anyone reads this one day, it doesn't actually delete them ... after you put the range in it removes the scores correctly, but if you put the range back to how it was .. the incorrect scores will come back. In my case users reported the wrong scores ... I fixed the bug ... did the trick above .. but didnt work because the wrong scores still came back after relaxed the range.