# Reset live gamecenter leaderboard data

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear live gamecenter leaderboard data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859915/how-to-clear-live-gamecenter-leaderboard-data)

I'm introducing some balancing changes in my game (making it harder) and I want to start over the leaderboard. Is it possible?